# Fuse symbolic link resolution under chroot

Tags: linux, fuse, chroot

I am creating a fuse-based filesystem very similar to the example [passthrough_fh](https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse/blob/master/example/passthrough.c). Where I log some statistics in my handlers before calling the underlying system call.

I use this with a debian Wheezy chroot image from debboostrap. The idea is to mirror wheezy/ into my mountpoint, then a process will chroot into the mountpoint and all activities will be recorded through my fuse fs.

The OS seems to handle path resolution with chroot nicely. That is, if the chrooted process does `stat("/bin/ls")`, from my fuse process I see `stat("wheezy/bin/ls")`.

However I'm not sure how to handle symlinks. For example the file
`wheezy/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`
points to
`/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so`

So when I call `stat("wheezy/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2")` it won't just work, since the OS will try to dereference the symlink `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so` instead of the correct `wheezy/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so`.

This is a simplified example, I can't just prepend `wheezy/` to all paths, I want to also support applications which do not chroot, or chroot multiple times.

I can think of some less than ideals ways to do this, e.g. check `/proc/pid/root/` to get the root of the process in case of chroot, but then I have to always check if a file is a symbolic link.

Is there a better way or general way fuse based file systems handle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

After contacting the fuse-devel mailing list, I received the following response:

```
If you are performing this stat(2) for GETATTR or LOOKUP, you should
be using lstat(2) instead. This will tell the kernel that you found a
symlink and it should keep managing path resolution correctly for you.
```

That is, use `lstat(2)` when handling LOOKUP or GETATTR, use the results of lstat to fill the fuse struct. From there, the kernel will automatically handle the name resolution (even for symbolic links, and processes running inside a chroot).